# how to set StageText fontSize value, to show text in same size in different screen size by as3?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I want to show a StageText in android application ( developed by flash cs6 & actionscrip 3) :

```
var input_text:StageText;
input_text.stage = stage;
input_text.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
input_text.fontSize = 40;
```

this font size is good for some android devices screen,little for some devices , and big for some devices !
how can I calculate suitable size for .fontSize to show the text same in all devices screen?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no easy way to do this with a StageText.  You could create some kind of formula with `flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX` & `Capabilities.screenDPI` that might get you close to your goal.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis yes, I tried these , but .screenDPI return wrong value !

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the DPI from the actual server string? (sometimes on iOS it's a different value, not sure about Android)  `var realDpi:Number = Number(flash.system.Capabilities.serverString.split("&DP=", 2)[1]);`

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I checked it , this return wrong value too on ondroid

Comment: @Fanous but it works correctly on iOS? Also what is the wrong result vs expected values for _Screen DPI_ and  _W x H_ resolution? Also what is detected _Stage_ width and height? Maybe there's a correctness with all the numbers... Otherwise it's time to [**research everything**](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=CwdVVqvOHYSIOt7LgdAP#q=as3+detect+screen+size+android) possible. You really need to know the screen size to make your text sizing algorithm. PS: Why not just work with detected W/H sizes (as proportional estimates etc)?

Comment: Does [**this article**](http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2012/12/multiscreen-support-in-mobile-air-applications/?lang=en) help?